# Typescript - push splitted string to array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I write an application using angular 2.

I have an input and I want to enter list of string and later split them by comma.

Input: Item1, Item2, Item3

Entered string I have to split by comma.

```
addItems(toSplit: string) {
   splitted: string[] = toSplit.split(",");
}
```

And I have an object:

```
export class Foo {
   items: string[];
}
```

How can I push all splitted string to foo.items?

Comment: What is `Foo` class and why did you export it?

Comment: In addition, you should declare your array: let splitted: string[] = toSplit.split(",");

Comment: And for those not fluent in English: "Split" is an irregular verb with irregular adjective derivatives, there is no word "splitted" in English, even though that is how you would make the past tense and adjective normally. It's just "split" even though it's used where -ed words are usually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I have an object

That's not an object, it's a class. (Okay, granted, it's *also* an object.) To access `items`, first you need an instance to access it on:

```
const instanceOfFoo: Foo = new Foo();
```

Then, once you have that instance and you have the array from `split`, you can either:

1. *Replace* the array on your `Foo` instance:

   ```
   instanceOfFoo.items = splitted;
   ```

   or
2. *Add* those to your items (e.g., if you may do this more than once with the same `Foo`):

   ```
   instanceOfFoo.items.push(...splitted);
   ```

   That `...` is spread notation, which should be supported in TypeScript via transpilation. If you want to be old-fashioned instead:

   ```
   instanceOfFoo.items.push.apply(instanceOfFoo.items, splitted);
   ```

If you already have the split string *before* you create `Foo`, you could provide it as an argument to the constructor and then do one of these within the constructor, whichever better suits your need:

```
// Using the array provided directly
export class Foo {
    constructor(public items: string[] = []) {
    }
}
```

or

```
// Copying the given array
export class Foo {
    public items: string[] = [];
    constructor(items: string[]) {
        this.items.push(...items);
    }
}
```

Then using either of those:

```
const instanceOfFoo: Foo = new Foo(splitted);
```

---

Side note: You're missing a `let` or `const` in your method (I assume it's a method, given the lack of `function` in front of it):

```
addItems(toSplit: string) {
   const splitted: string[] = toSplit.split(",");
// ^---- here, should be const or let depending on whether you want
// to be able to change it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `constructor` for your `typescript` class.

```
export class Foo {
   constructor(private items: string[]){}
}
```

Now you can create a class object which has your **splitted** array.

```
var foo = new Foo(splitted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:)

```
class Split {
    splitted: string[];
    addItems(toSplit: string) {
        this.splitted = toSplit.split(",");
    }
}


export class Foo {
    items: string[];
}

var demo = new Foo();
var test = new Split();
test.addItems("Item1,Item2,Item3");

demo.items = test.splitted;

console.log(demo.items);
```